# How to find out the Runge-Kutta 4 constants for numerically evaluating an nth order IVP?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

I know how to use the RK 4 method for a first order differential equation of the form:

$$y' = f(x, y(x))$$

$$y_{k+1} = y_k + (G_1 + 2G_2 + 2G_3 + G_4)*dx/6$$

where $G_1 + 2G_2 + 2G_3 + G_4$ are calculated as:

$$G_1 = f(t_k, x_k)$$
$$G_2 = f(t_k + 0.5*dx, x_k + G_1*dx)$$
$$G_3 = f(t_k + 0.5*dx, x_k + G_2*dx)$$
$$G_4 = f(t_k + dx, x_k + G_1*dx)$$

But what to do if the differential equation is of $n th$ order and it being written as a function of $y'$ contains other derivatives of y as well ?

Lets say the $n th$ order differential equation is written as follows:

$$D_ny = f(x, D_1y, D_2y, ..., D_{n-1}y)$$

where $D_n$ denotes the $n th$ derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$

How do you go about calculating $G_1, G_2, G_3, G_4$ ?

I am aware of the method of decomposing an nth order DE into n first order equations but I am also aware that it can be solved as it is numerically as shown in here : https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/004579499290121F

But I am having difficulty understanding precisely how the algorithm works as I can understand exactly how the $G_i$'s are calculated and then are used to find the state variables of the next step.

Comment: As I read it, you understand using the derivatives array as state vector for the first-order system and applying the method to it. You are wondering if there are specific methods that apply to n-th order DE. For second-order DE such exist, like the symplectic methods or Numerov's method or diverse methods in molecular dynamics. Using finite differences is an educational experience but usually not worth it (in contrast to finite element or volume methods).

Comment: The cited article looks fringe, from reading the abstract. There were better methods than RK4 in the 1970s, and the transformation into a first-order system was common knowledge in the 1990s. Of merit could have been a memory-efficient implementation, but that is not mentioned in the abstract.